# Firebase database updating child value again and again without meting codition true

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app there is an option for referrals, I am using the firebase database to update the wallet if referral code matched, but the problem is user account is credting successfully but agent account(who referred )is credting multiple times like over and over continuously and that's the issue,

```
public void checkreffercode() {

    final String refferalcode = editText.getText().toString();
    if (refferalcode.equals("")) {

        Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "Refferal code is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } else {
        final DatabaseReference reffercoderef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Reffercode");
        final DatabaseReference agentwallet = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        final DatabaseReference userwalletstat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Refferal");
        final DatabaseReference userwallet = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("walletcoin");

        userwalletstat.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String statous = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (statous == null) {

                    Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "data is null in Refferal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else if (statous.equals("notcredited")) {
                    //here check all the feild....
                    reffercoderef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(refferalcode).exists()) {
                                final String Uid = dataSnapshot.child(refferalcode).getValue(String.class);
                                userwallet.setValue(String.valueOf(5000));
                                agentwallet.child(Uid).child("walletcoin").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                        String agentbalance = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                        Integer agentbalinint = Integer.parseInt(agentbalance);
                                        Integer updatedbalu = (agentbalinint + 5000);
                                        agentwallet.child(Uid).child("walletcoin").setValue(String.valueOf(updatedbalu));
                                        userwalletstat.setValue("credited");

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "error on updating agent balance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                    }
                                });


                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "Refferal code not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "Database error on checking refferal code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }
                    });


                    //last

                } else {


                    Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "Both wallet has been credited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(ReferalActivity.this, "Database error on checking account status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


    }


}

public void updateref(View view) {

    Button button=findViewById(R.id.refbutton);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReferalActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
    progressDialog.getActionBar();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    checkreffercode();
    progressDialog.cancel();

}
```

Here is my xml code

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Refer code"
android:id="@+id/refercode"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:padding="20dp"/>



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Update"
    android:onClick="updateref"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/refbutton"
    android:textColor="#51122e"/>
```

Comment: If you only want it to happen once you should use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) instead of `addValueEventListener`. Also i would highly recommend AGAINST using an eventlistener within an eventlistener within an eventlistener

Comment: Dear, so what should I do , I have to use all 3 value event listener under singlevalueevent listener or please suggest me any good way to achieve this

Comment: My problem solved by your solution dear, 
I just used all the singlevalueeventListener
And solved... Thanks

Comment: @AndréKool it's solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ValueEventListener` on `userwalletstat` reference. The problem is that with `ValueEventListener` is that, it gets called every time a value changes under `userwalletstat` ("referal") child. Inside your  `else if (statous.equals("notcredited"))` condition, you are using another `ValueEventListener` in which you are setting setting the value like this `userwallet.setValue(String.valueOf(5000));`

So your first ValueEventListener gets activated because it's a `ValueEventListener`. So your code is kind of like a recusive function and it is bad. So in order to fix it, you should replace your `ValueEventListeners` with `SingleValueEventListener`. You can learn more about them [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and scroll down to **Read Data Once** section.

Basically, you need to replace

`userwalletstat.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`

with

`userwalletstat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {`

and do the same for other listeners like :

`reffercoderef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {`

`agentwallet.child(Uid).child("walletcoin").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {`

Also, I don't know how your data structure is setup but it is not a good idea to have a listener inside a listener inside a listener. Maybe you should reorganize your datastructure.